# Setting up a second vertex array object has led to odd rendering

Tags: c++, opengl

So i have a couple classes. A renderer and box2drenderer. Now both use their own vertex buffer and their own vertex array object. The Renderer is instantiated first with the following code:

```
glGenBuffers(1, &ebo);
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);

GLfloat vertices[] = {
    //  Position(2) Color(3)     Texcoords(2)
    0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, // Top-left
    1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, // Top-right
    1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, // Bottom-right
    0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f  // Bottom-left
};

glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);
GLuint elements[] = {
    0, 1, 2,
    2, 3, 0
};

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, ebo);
glBufferData(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(elements), elements, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

GLint posAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "position");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(posAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(posAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);

GLint colAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "color");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(colAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(colAttrib, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(2 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

GLint texAttrib = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "texcoord");
glEnableVertexAttribArray(texAttrib);
glVertexAttribPointer(texAttrib, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 7 * sizeof(GLfloat), (void*)(5 * sizeof(GLfloat)));

glBindVertexArray(0);

glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
projection = glm::ortho(0.0f, width, height, 0.0f);

glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(projection));
glUseProgram(0);
```

Then I call the setup function for the box2d:

```
void Box2DRenderer::setRenderer(Renderer * r) {
    this->renderer = r;

    const GLchar * fragSource =
    "#version 150 core\n\
    precision mediump float;\n\
    uniform vec4 u_color;\n\
    out vec4 Color;\n\
    \n\
    void main()\n\
    {\n\
      Color = u_color;\n\
    }";

    const GLchar * vertSource =
    "#version 150 core\n\
    uniform mediump mat4 u_projection;\n\
    uniform mediump float u_pointSize;\n\
    in vec2 a_position;\n\
    \n\
    void main()\n\
    {\n\
      gl_PointSize = u_pointSize;\n\
      gl_Position = u_projection * vec4(a_position, 0.0, 1.0);\n\
    }";

    this->renderer->compileProgram(vertSource, fragSource, vertShader, fragShader, shaderProgram);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
    glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);

    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(vertices), vertices, GL_DYNAMIC_DRAW);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_projection"), 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(this->renderer->getProjectionMatrix()));

    GLuint positionLocation = glGetAttribLocation(shaderProgram, "a_position");
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(positionLocation);
    glVertexAttribPointer(positionLocation, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 2 * sizeof(GLfloat), 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);

    colorLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_color");
    pointSizeLocation = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "u_pointSize");
    glUseProgram(0);
}
```

The Renderer for now just draws textures. So i draw the player via the method:

```
void Renderer::renderTexture(sf::FloatRect &bounds, Texture &texture, Region *region) {
    glm::mat4 model;
    model = glm::translate(model, glm::vec3(bounds.left, bounds.top, 0.0f));
    model = glm::scale(model, glm::vec3(bounds.width, bounds.height, 0.0f));
    GLint modelMat = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "mMatrix");
    glUniformMatrix4fv(modelMat, 1, GL_FALSE, glm::value_ptr(model));

    float x = region->pos.x / texture.getWidth();
    float y = region->pos.y / texture.getHeight();
    float rx = (region->width + region->pos.x) / texture.getWidth();
    float ry = (region->height + region->pos.y) / texture.getHeight();
    GLfloat vertices[] = {
        //  Position(2) Color(3)     Texcoords(2)
        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, x, y, // Top-left
        1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, rx, y, // Top-right
        1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, rx, ry, // Bottom-right
        0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, x, ry  // Bottom-left
    };

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture.getTextureId());
    glBindVertexArray(vao);
    glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
    glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
    glBindVertexArray(0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
}
```

Now, if i don't initialize the box2d renderer, it works fine. If i have the box2d renderer, the texture coords are getting messed up. The whole texture seems to get drawn across the screen instead of regions at their correct place.

Given i'm turning on and off the BindVertexArray, I feel like I shouldn't have an issue, but for the life of me I can't figure it out. I can post screenshots of the difference if you'd like.

Comment: At the very end of the code you posted, you call `glBufferSubData()` without binding a buffer first. So that call will modify the data in whatever buffer happens to be bound at the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably fell victim to a fairly common misconception: Contrary to what you might have expected, the `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding is **not** part of the VAO state.

At the tail end of the posted code you have this sequence:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
glBufferSubData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0, sizeof(vertices), vertices);
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, 6, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0);
glBindVertexArray(0);
```

The `glBufferSubData()` call will modify data in the currently bound `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER`, which is the buffer that you last made a `glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, ...)` call for. This is unrelated to the buffer you had bound when you previously used the VAO.

For additional illustration, here is a typical call sequence:

```
glBindVertexArray(vaoA);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboA);

glBindVertexArray(vaoB);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vboB);

glBindVertexArray(vaoA);
```

The current `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding at the end of this sequence is `vboB`. Since the binding is not part of the VAO state, it is simply based on the most recent `glBindBuffer()` call.

All you need to do to fix this is to add the `glBindBuffer()` call before `glBufferSubData()`.

Note that the `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding **is** part of the VAO state. This may seem inconsistent, but it's not. The VAO bundles all the vertex setup state that is used by draw commands. The `GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding controls which index buffer is used by draw commands, so it is part of this state. On the other hand, the current `GL_ARRAY_BUFFER` binding has no effect on the draw command, and is therefore not part of the VAO state.